# Decompress a PSC File

Tags: mysql, backup-restoration, compression, navicat

I need to restore a database that was backed up using navicat's compressed backup feature. But on the restore, there's an error coming up on one of the tables.

I can't look at the SQL statements in the file directly because they're compressed, and I don't know what compression format it's in.

Does anyone know of a way to decompress this file into a regular text file?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by dragging the backup file into the listing on the backups tab of Navicat, and then right clicking on that entry and selecting the "Extract SQL" option. This then allowed me to save out the raw SQL.